# uninstalling/reinstalling wifi Drivers in ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers

Hi so the internet seems to be working fine on every device except my laptop. Sometimes it would even stop showing the available networks. I recently switched to ubuntu and this used to happen on windows too but a simple reinstallation of wifi driver or renabling the wifi driver after disabling it would solve the issue.

Possible solutions I am looking for:

**1.** Is there a device manager utility in ubuntu like in windows where I can disable/enable drivers or reinstall them?
If not then

**2.** How to disable wifi drivers in ubuntu?

**3.** How to reinstall/uninstall wifi drivers?

Edited to add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
```

Using ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Have you tried toggling the hardware switch or button that controls wifi?

Answer (score 4):

This wireless device "QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter" is supported by Linux kernel and does not require any drivers.

Problems with your wireless device may be caused by a kernel bug, a hardware problem, or other reasons.

If this happened on Windows too, it means that most likely it is a hardware issue.

You can reload the in-tree driver by running:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Thank you! 18.04 crashed after an Alt-F2 "r". When I rebooted, no wireless adapter was found. These two modprobe commands brought it back. Unfortunately, I now need to use them after every reboot.

Comment: I ran `sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci`, then my laptop hang. any clue guys, what just happened?

Answer (score -1):

```
terminal:
rfkill list
Example:
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
Turn OFF WiFi
rfkill block wifi OR using “rfkill list” index rfkill block 0
Turn ON WiFi
rfkill unblock wifi OR using “rfkill list” index rfkill unblock 0
```

[How can I bring back disappeared or hard-blocked wifi on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1364715/how-can-i-bring-back-disappeared-or-hard-blocked-wifi-on-linux)